# Como quebrar minha String corretamente?

Tags: spring, request, split

Bom, estou utilizando o {split()} para extrair dados enviados de uma API. Estou fazendo um get dentro do código e pegando a resposta para tratamento. A resposta desse get é longa e preciso somente do corpo... {body}. Quando utilizo o {response.body} junto com split acabo recebendo um vetor separado por caractere e não por linha como normalmente. Segue código abaixo:

```
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

        String respostaRequest = new String(response.body().string());
        
        String respostaAutomatica = respostaRequest.split("\r")[0];
        
        System.out.println(respostaAutomatica);
                    
        System.out.println(respostaAutomatica.length());
        
        String idCaixaOperacaoRetorno = respostaAutomatica.split("|")[3] + 
                respostaAutomatica.split("|")[4] + 
                respostaAutomatica.split("|")[5] + 
                respostaAutomatica.split("|")[6] + 
                respostaAutomatica.split("|")[7] +
                respostaAutomatica.split("|")[8] +
                respostaAutomatica.split("|")[9];

        String status = respostaAutomatica.split("|")[0] + respostaAutomatica.split("|")[1];

    
        
        
        if (respostaAutomatica != null && respostaAutomatica != "") {
            
            

            if (status.equals("OK")) {
                                    
                try {
                    
                    
                    System.out.println("Id Caixa Operação: " + idCaixaOperacaoRetorno);
                    System.out.println("Satus: " + status);
                    
                    
                    
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

            }

        }
```

Quero poder separar a string por linha e não por caráctere.

Comment: Já descobri meu problema, agora tenho que descobrir como resolver hehe... Seguinte o método split não está conseguindo interpretar o "|" como separador da string e ai separa cada carácrete. Preciso entender mais sobre carácteres especiais para poder resolver isso.

Comment: Pronto, resolvido...

Na função split quando pede o regex, coloquei assim:

String status[] = respostaRequest.split("\\|");

Isso foi falta de experiência da minha parte, obrigado quem possa ter pensado para responder.

Answer (score 0):

Quando eu colocava o seguinte código:

```
String status[] = respostaRequest.split("|");
```

O Java separava a string respostaRequest por caráctere e não dividia corretamente pelo "|", então encontrei em alguns lugares para testar com "\|" e ficou assim:

```
String status[] = respostaRequest.split("\\|");
```

Então a String OK|6339105|Isento foi dividida em um vetor com valores.

> Citação